# Getting the current number of messages in the ring buffer

Tags: spring, reactor, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I am using Spring's Reactor pattern in my web application. Internally it uses **LMAX's RingBuffer** implementation as one of it's message queues. I was wondering if there's any way to find out the current RingBuffer occupancy dynamically. It would help me determine the number of producers and consumers needed (and also their relative rates), and whether the RingBuffer as a message queue is being used optimally. 
I tried the **getBacklog()** of the **reactor.event.dispatch.AbstractSingleThreadDispatcher** class, but it  seems to always give the same value: the size of the RingBuffer I used while instantiating the reactor.

Any light on the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use **com.lmax.disruptor.Sequencer.remainingCapacity()**
To have access to the instance of **Sequencer** you have to create it explicitly as well as **RingBuffer**.

In my case initialization of outcoming Disruptor

```
Disruptor<MessageEvent> outcomingDisruptor = 
    new Disruptor<MessageEvent>(
        MyEventFactory.getInstance(),
        RING_BUFFER_OUT_SIZE, 
        MyExecutor.getInstance(), 
        ProducerType.SINGLE, new BlockingWaitStrategy());
```

transforms into

```
this.sequencer = 
    SingleProducerSequencer(RING_BUFFER_OUT_SIZE, new BlockingWaitStrategy());
RingBuffer ringBuffer = 
    new RingBuffer<MessageEvent>(MyEventFactory.getInstance(), sequencer);
Disruptor<MessageEvent> outcomingDisruptor = 
    new Disruptor<MessageEvent>(ringBuffer, MyExecutor.getInstance());
```

and then

```
this.getOutCapacity() {
    return sequencer.remainingCapacity();
}
```

---

### UPDATE

small bug :|
we need **outMessagesCount** instead of **getOutCapacity**.

```
public long outMessagesCount() {
    return RING_BUFFER_OUT_SIZE - sequencer.remainingCapacity();
}
```

Comment: but what if you need to monitor the disruptor `remainingCapacity` inside another framework where `sequencer` is not exposed? e.g. the problem is with log4j2 async loggers based on disruptor: as far I investigated there is no valid way to get `sequencer` there.

Comment: Looks like one option is to just use ringBuffer.remainingCapacity(), which is public.

Comment: @yetanothercoder is there any way in log4j2 to expose remainingCapacity as a bean?

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of **reactor-core** in [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectreactor/reactor-core/1.1.4.RELEASE) (version 1.1.4 RELEASE) does not have a way to dynamically monitor the state of the message queue. However, after going through the reactor code on [github](https://github.com/reactor/reactor), I found the **[TraceableDelegatingDispatcher](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/event/dispatch/TraceableDelegatingDispatcher.java)**, which allows tracing the message queue (if supported by the underlying dispatcher implementation) at runtime, via its `remainingSlots()` method. The easiest option was to compile the source and use it.